# When I am running Node Js code ( I am beginner learner) I am getting port under use error

Tags: node.js

I am getting address already in use error when running node js code in Windows. Is there a way to check this in Windows(tried checking in task manager but no luck).

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: **address already in use :::3000**
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1740:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1876:7)
at Object. (c:\Users\Dr Padma srinivas.000\Desktop\GET_CODE\index.js:16:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3000
}

Node.js v18.16.0

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.115 seconds

The below is the code:

```
const http=require('http');
const server=http.createServer((req,res) => {
    const url=req.url;
    if(url == '/'){ 
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<body>Hello</body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        res.end();
    

    }
   
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have another instance of Node (or another dev application) running on port 3000.

You can use `netstat -aof | findstr :3000` to find what the existing application is.